# Iterating over all tags in a string containing HTML using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using a rich text editor type control, which is a written as a jQuery plugin. It basically inserts an IFrame onto the page, and makes it editable - fairly standard for rich text controls.

Now, what I'm looking to do is improve upon an option which removes all formatting from the text editor. Currently it is being done with a large list of regular expressions, and a quick google search suggests that this is not the correct way to go about it. I'm looking to allow this unformatting some degree of flexibility, so that I can leave certain tags in (like paragraph tags).

I was trying to use the jQuery built in DOM parsing to do this easily, but I seem to be having trouble.

Let's assume I have a sample HTML string:

```
<Body><p>One <strong>Two</strong> <em>Three</em></p></Body>
```

I'm looking to un-format it so that all non paragraph tags are removed. So, I'd be expecting the output to be a string which looks like this:

```
<Body><p>One Two Three</p></Body>
```

Sample code:

```
//Some very simple HTML obtained from an editable iframe
var text = '<Body><p>One <strong>Two</strong> <em>Three</em></p></Body>';
var $text = $(text);

//All tags which are not paragraphs
$(':not(p)',$text).each(function() {
    //Replace the tag + content with just content
    $(this).html($(this).text());
});

//I'll be honest, I found this snippet somewhere else on stackoverflow,
//It seems to parse the jquery object back into an HTML string.
var returnVal = "";
$text.each(function(){
    returnVal += $(this).clone().wrap('<p>').parent().html();
});
//Should be equal to '<p>One Two Three</p>'       
return returnVal;
```

This seems like it should work, but unfortunately it doesn't. In the above example, 'returnVal' is the same as the input (minus the 'body' header tags). Is there anything I'm obviously doing wrong here?

Comment: John, it's an spaghetti code! can you give us a summary what is the input and what is the desired output you want.

Comment: Is it really that bad? I tried to make it clear. Hold up, and let me edit it a little bit.

Comment: Well, it's bad because it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Characterizing the code as spaghetti... is just wrong.  It reads perfectly fine.  You do have a bug which I'll address shortly.

Comment: By the way, I've checked several similar threads: to my surprise, in one thread the most upvoted answer was about... yep, using regexes. )

Comment: @raina77ow - As Jon Bentley suggests in his classic "Writing Efficient Programs", writing code that is more efficient generally makes it harder to understand and maintain.  In this case, but utilizing the browser's dom parsing, we auto-validate much of the HTML in a way that regex never could.  This solution will be slower than regex, but also more bulletproof (and more understandable).  The trade-off depends on the project.  : )

Comment: Of course, and I'd prefer the `parsing` way 9 times out of 10, even though my regex-fu is (well, usually, but not always) good enough to see how it can be made with the `Chtulhu` way. ))

Comment: Thats great, thanks very much to both of you. Just as a small aside, would the best way of controlling tags to ignore be something like `$(':not(p em)',$text).each(function()`?

Comment: `$text.not('p').not('em')`, `$(':not(p,em)', $text)` or `$text.not('p,em')` should all work (although I'm not 100% on the ':not(p,em)' syntax off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...snip
// Here's your bug:
$(':not(p)',$text).each(function() {
//  You can't use .html() to replace the content 
//     $(this).html($(this).text());
//   You have to replace the entire element, not just its contents:
    $(this).replaceWith($(this).text());
});
...snip
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace this line:

```
$(this).html($(this).text());
```

... with this:

```
$(this).replaceWith($(this).text());
```

... and it should work (at least it works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rLehn/)).